# pry show-model command doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, gemfile, pry

I've got the pry gem installed in my rails app and I've been facing with the error when I turn it on:

```
[1] pry(main)> show-model User
ArgumentError: Unknown validator: 'PrsenceValidator'
from /Users/~/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.6/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:120:in `rescue in block in validates'
```

On the other hand, such commands as User.all and User.find(1) succcessfully runs to show the information of the table.
In addition, as I have several models inside my app, none of which I had success with "show-model Xxx" command, I suppose it's not user model related issue.

My gem file includes the following code:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'pry-doc'
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'pry-stack_explorer'
  gem 'rails-erd'
end
```

I've used pry before and this is the first time the pry has reported such an error.
I'd appreciate your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo error in your model user.rb, prsence is wrong

It should be like

```
validates :name, presence: true
```

Comment: As far as I see there are no typos in the user.rb file...
I have also commented out all the codes in the user.rb file to run show-model User command, but the result remains to be tha same.

Comment: Your error says so `ArgumentError: Unknown validator: 'PrsenceValidator'`, can you post user.rb file, and also check other model

Comment: Oh I've found the typo in other model and I happened to type "prsence"...Now the issue has been fixed. Thank you for your help!